# How to display event title in bold if it falls within the phone's time range in React Native?

Tags: typescript, react-native, time

I'm working on a React Native app where I need to display event titles in bold if they fall within the current time range on the user's phone. Otherwise, the title should be displayed in normal font. I'm looking for a solution to achieve this functionality.

I have the following code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

interface ConferenceSession {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  startTime: string;
  endTime: string;
  room: string;
  speaker: string;
}

const ConferenceProgram: React.FC = () => {
  const [conferenceData, setConferenceData] = useState<ConferenceSession[]>([]);
  const [currentSessionId, setCurrentSessionId] = useState<string>('');
  const [currentDateTime, setCurrentDateTime] = useState(new Date());

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://dev.monstercode.pl/program.json') // Zmień na odpowiedni URL
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => setConferenceData(data))
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setCurrentDateTime(new Date());
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const now = new Date();
    const currentSessionId = conferenceData.find(session => {
      const sessionStartTime = new Date(`${session.startTime}Z`);
      const sessionEndTime = new Date(`${session.endTime}Z`);
      return now >= sessionStartTime && now <= sessionEndTime;
    })?.id || '';
    setCurrentSessionId(currentSessionId);
  }, [currentDateTime, conferenceData]);

  const renderItem = ({ item }: { item: ConferenceSession }) => {
    const isCurrentSession = currentSessionId === item.id;

    return (
      <View
        style={{
          backgroundColor: isCurrentSession ? 'red' : 'white',
          padding: 10,
          marginBottom: 10,
        }}
      >
        <Text style={{ fontWeight: isCurrentSession ? 'bold' : 'normal', color: isCurrentSession ?'red' }}>{item.title}</Text>
        <Text>{item.startTime.substr(11, 5)} - {item.endTime.substr(11, 5)}</Text>
        <Text>{item.room}</Text>
        <Text>Prelegent: {item.speaker}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 16 }}>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold', marginBottom: 16 }}>Program konferencji</Text>
      <Text>Aktualna data i czas: {currentDateTime.toLocaleString()}</Text>
      <FlatList
        data={conferenceData}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default ConferenceProgram;
```

The code above displays the current time and the event title. However, I'm unsure how to check if the current time falls within a specific time range and apply the bold font style to the event title accordingly.

Could someone please provide guidance on how to achieve this functionality? I would greatly appreciate any help or suggestions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you create a function inside your component like this:

```
const getFontWeight = ({
  currentTime,
  startTime,
  endTime,
}: {
  currentTime: number;
  startTime: number;
  endTime: number;
}) => {
  return currentTime > startTime && currentTime < endTime
    ? {fontWeight: "bold"}
    : {fontWeight: "normal"};
};
```

Then you can call this function inside your TEXT component like this:

```
<Text
    style={{
      ...getFontWeight({
        currentTime: currentDateTime.getMiliSeconds(),
        startTime: item.startTime,
        endTime: item.endTime,
      }),
    }}>
</Text>;
```

*** Just keep in mind that all the values should be converted to "number", or "date" so the comparison is done correctly.